# Attributes internal working in aj for performance benefits in kdb

Tags: kdb

Considering the trade table 't' and quotes table 'q' in memory:

```
q)t:([] sym:`GOOG`AMZN`GOOG`AMZN; time:10:01 10:02 10:02 10:03; px:10 20 11 19)
q)q:([] sym:`GOOG`AMZN`AMZN`GOOG`AMZN; time:10:01 10:01 10:02 10:02 10:03; vol:100 200 210 110 220)
```

In order to get performance benefits applying grouped attribute on 'sym' column of q table and making 'time' column sorted within sym.
Using this, I can clearly see the performance benefits from it:

```
q)\t:1000000 aj[`sym`time;t;q]
9573
q)\t:1000000 aj[`sym`time;t;q1]
8761
q)\t:100000 aj[`sym`time;t;q]
968
q)\t:100000 aj[`sym`time;t;q1]
893
```

And in large tables the performance is far better.

Now, I'm trying to understand how it works internally when we are applying grouped attribute to sym column and sort time within sym.

My understanding is internally the aj should happen in below way, can someone please let me know the correct internal working?
* Since, grouped attribute is applied on sym; so it creates a hashtable for table q1, then since we are sorting on time so the internal q1 table might look like.

```
GOOG|(10:01;10:02)|(100;110)
AMZN|(10:01;10:02:10:03)|(200;210;220)
```

So in this case of q1, if the interpreter has to join (AMZN;10:02) of t table; it will directly find it in q1's hasttable in less time, but for joining same value(AMZN;10:02) of table 't' in table 'q' the interpreter will have to search linearly through table 'q' hence taking more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're on the right track, though we can't know for sure as we don't have access to the kdb source code to see precisely what it does.

If you look at the definition of aj you'll see that it's based on `bin`:

```
q)aj
k){.Q.ft[{d:x_z;$[&/j:-1<i:(x#z)bin x#y;y,'d i;+.[+.Q.ff[y]d;(!+d;j);:;.+d i j:&j]]}[x,();;0!z]]y}
```

specifically,

```
(`sym`time#q)bin `sym`time#t
```

and the `bin` documentation provides some more details on how `bin` behaves: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/bin/

I believe in the two-column case it will first match on the sym column and then use `bin` on the second column. Like you said, the grouped attribute on sym speeds up the matching of syms part and the sorting on time ensures the bin returns the correct results. Note that for on-disk queries it's optimal to put `` `p# `` on sym rather than `` `g# `` as the parted attribute is optimal for matching/retrieving by sym from disk.

Comment: On the money. To expand, `p#` will outperform `g#` nearly always, as the index you are retrieving and more clustered..